# Cannot find daemon log after running a daemon

Tags: c, linux, daemon

Here is my daemon:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define DAEMON_NAME "vdaemon"

void process(){

    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Writing to my Syslog");
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Set our Logging Mask and open the Log
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog(DAEMON_NAME, LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Entering Daemon");

    pid_t pid, sid;

   //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Change Directory
    //If we cant find the directory we exit with failure.
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Close Standard File Descriptors
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    //----------------
    //Main Process
    //----------------
    while(true){
        process();    //Run our Process
        sleep(2);    //Sleep for 2 seconds
    }

    //Close the log
    closelog ();
}
```

I compile it like,

```
gcc vdaemon.cpp -o vdaemon
```

And run it

```
./vdaemon
```

Then when I get

```
shishir@dewsworld:~/daemon$ ps -A | grep --color='auto' "vdaemon"
 5060 ?        00:00:00 vdaemon
```

Then I get no log

```
shishir@dewsworld:~/daemon$ dmesg | grep --color='auto' "Writing to my Syslog"
shishir@dewsworld:~/daemon$
```

I need to know how to get the log.

Comment: Look in /var/log/messages or wherever your syslog logs.

Comment: If you still can't find your messages, look at your `syslog` daemon's configuration.  It may be discarding LOG_NOTICE messages, or LOG_USER messages.  Not very likely, but you can configure what the `syslog` daemon reports at the system level, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right. I needed to configure them.

Answer (score 1):

You've been advised to look at the `/var/log/messages` area to see where the `syslog` daemon would be writing to.  If you still can't find your messages there, then you should look at your syslog daemon's configuration. It may be discarding LOG_NOTICE messages, or LOG_USER messages. You can configure what the syslog daemon reports at the system level.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `/var/log/messages`, it should be there. `dmesg` will displays the system message buffer by default

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nearly the same as the [daemon(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) library function, and you should call [openlog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) *after* calling `daemon` (i.e. *after* the `fork`-s), not before.